# Parent module as dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

My application has an angular module:

```
var io = angular.module('IO_Operations', []);
```

The module also has a Service to realize input/output things:

```
io.service('ioService', function () {
    var dataStore = {};

    return {
        pushData: function (key, value) {
            dataStore[key] = value;
        },
        getData: function (key) {
            return dataStore[key];
        }
    };
});
```

Later I want to store the `dataStore` variable with JSON in a file as object.

Now i have an `iframe` in my aplication to display some content with tabs, you could call it something like a browser.

To give the ability to make some settings, I wanted to do it in one iframe.
In order to save the data to a file, I need to call the `IO_Service`, which is in the parent application

In my iframe I have a module:

```
var settings = angular.module("settings", []);
```

with a controller

```
settings.controller("MyController", function ($scope) { ... }
```

So I need to declare a dependency for the parent module to use the `ioService` in order to call the `pushData` function.

Does anyone have some tips for me to realize this?

Comment: Maybw silly suggestion, but can't you put the settings of each tab and tabs outside the iframe? That way you will be able to control it

Comment: I've done it like this now, the tabs are just iframes which loads html-dicuments. The settings I now have my settings directly implemented in the application to share the angular magic with my other controllers :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything [DoctorMick says here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480589/379538) is correct and must be done in order to access the service at all in your controller.

Additionally, you have to address the fact that the parent and iframe don't share any Javascript context:

**The Same-Domain Answer**

In your module, `dataStore` needs to be either `window.dataStore` or `window.parent.dataStore` (or possibly `window.top.datastore`) depending on if the module has been loaded into an iframe or as the main page:

```
io.service('ioService', function () {
    var inIframe = (window.parent !== window); // or (window.top !== window);

    // If we are in the iframe, we want to use the parent's dataStore,
    // If we are not in the iframe, we are the parent, so use ours.
    var dataStore = inIframe ? window.parent.dataStore : window.dataStore;

    dataStore = dataStore || {};

    return {
        pushData: function (key, value) {
            dataStore[key] = value;
        },
        getData: function (key) {
            return dataStore[key];
        }
    };
});
```

Or something to that effect.  Basically, figure out if you're being loaded in the iframe or parent and either attach to your own (as parent) `dataStore` or the parent's `dataStore`.

**The Cross-Domain Answer**

The main frame and the iframe are totally independent - they might as well (almost) be two different browser tabs - so they don't share anything from a Javascript data perspective.  Without using some type of iframe communication library or using an api (via WebSockets, maybe?) to back it up, you're not going to be able to get the two frames to communicate.

If you reconsider your problem as being two distinct applications - the 'browser container' and a collection of 'browsers' - and look for an appropriate application-to-application communication, that might help.

*More concretely, assuming you want a client-side solution, your `pushData(key, value)` and `getData(key)` methods in the `ioService` just need to wrap a communication mechanism built using either the native [Window.postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) or a library like [postmessage](https://github.com/daepark/postmessage) or [porthole](https://github.com/ternarylabs/porthole).*

Answer (score 0):

All you should have to do is let the settings module know is has a dependency on the IO operations module and once that is done you can just use the IO service as if it were in the same module, like so:

```
var settings = angular.module("settings", ["IO_Operations"]);

settings.controller("MyController", function ($scope, ioService) { ... }
```

Comment: the settings module is in an iframe, with this method it does not work, I need to say angular, that it is a parent module.
Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I missed that rather key bit of information when I read the question, silly me. :)  If you have angular in a page and an iframe won't that give you two separate angular "instances" with no way of communicating between them?  Is there a reason you need to use an iframe?

Comment: Well its an application which basically use tabs to display multiple websites and I thought it would be cool to have the settings in a tab like in Firefox.
Well the Javascript also can communicate, therefore I just need to use parent..
May be you are right because I need to load the anular.js file again in my settings webpage.
I think about make the settings just in another window, perhaps that easier ...

Comment: If it possible to communicate between a parent and an iframe apparently, but you'd need to use events rather than dependencies.  I'll not provide an answer as I've never tried it but this link should help: http://charemza.name/blog/posts/angularjs/iframe/same-domain-iframe-communication/

Comment: Thanks for this, but before I try this I want to try another way:
my idea is to create the module in the parent - parent.angular.module(...), so the dependency should work. Now I have the Problem, that I need to "execute" angular in the HTML-File, which is loaded in the iframe, but when I load angular again the connection gets lost (of course...), maybe I could send the angular instance from the parent down to the child or something, so that the directives gets solved ...